# Why an IBOutlet var has value when run at simulator, but produce nil when run at device?

Tags: ios, swift

So I have a weird situation. I have a view controller which acts like a tab bar controller (but I made the system it myself). Let's call it "tabbed view controller". Within it, I instantiate 4 other view controllers which each has tableview of their own. I take the root view of those view controllers and add it as subview on my tabbed view controller. I of course also save the 4 view controllers into an array of view controllers in the tabbed view controller.

When ran on simulator, all of those 4 view controllers work fine as expected. The table showed list correctly. The bottom tab bar works fine to switch between view controllers back and forth. Everything looks cool.

But when I ran this on my device, I always greeted with error everytime I access the table view outlet at any of child view controllers. "Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value". When I inspect the value using debugger, the table view outlet is nil. And even if I make the reference to table view optional, the table view outlet was never changed, still nil all the time. So I got an empty screen instead of table. But the bottom tab bar still working fine.

EDIT: I should also mention that I didn't see any trace of table view at all when I do debug view hierarchy. It feels almost like I was just creating a generic view controller using `let vc = MyViewController.init()`. But if that was the case too for simulator, I probably can narrow the issue further. The problem is, in simulator, it works correctly, the child root view is populated with subviews correctly.

So I did another experiment. I add a simple square UIView with red background on top of table view in the child view controller. At simulator, the red square view displayed correctly in the middle and on top of table view. At device, there's also no trace at all of the red square view, no trace of table view either.

This is the code that I use to instantiate view controller:

```
let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil);
let vc = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MyViewController") as! MyViewController;
```

Why is this happened? How to solve this?

Comment: no clue. That's weird. 1) I would just clean my build + derived data + restart mac. 2) Also do you have anything that would change the flow of your code when it's sim vs. non-sim? 3) Did you also try different devices? Or different simulator versions? 4) Is your simulator and device of the same kind?

Comment: @Honey 1) I have just cleaned up the data, rebuild, and still the same. 2) No, there's none. This app is still at early stages, so there's none of those weird flow complicated things involved, yet. 3) I tried on both iPod touch and iPhone 6+, same issues. The simulator I use is iPhone 5s. 4) Now I just tried iPhone 6+ simulator, and the result is still success. Now what I'm going to do is to try to create new storyboard, create new view controller, copy all the subviews to there, create new class, and copy all the class content there, and see who knows if it fixes the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The solution for this is to create new storyboard, create new view controller, copy and paste the subviews from old view controller to new view controller. And then create new class, copy and paste the class content from old file to new file. Don't forget to link all the IBOutlet. Using this, the view controller works fine. I suspect this has something to do with git conflicts we experience several times that involved storyboards. Probably we didn't resolve the conflicts correctly, and there were some important parts of the storyboards erased. Probably. Just a guess.

Comment: weird/interesting!